# Can I get the iterator / iterated variable from xargs?

Tags: bash, parameters, iterator, pipe, xargs

```
./script1 | xargs -L1 ./script2 {}
```

`script1` gives me lines of output, I want to pass each line of output into `script2`.

Right now, it's running `script2` without any parameters.

How do I give `script2` the values of each line that `xargs` gets?. I thought `{}` was that variable.

Comment: I suggest to remove `{}`.

Comment: When I remove `{}` it runs as if script2 has no output.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `-I` option of `xargs` to pass each line of output into
  `script2` separately as in

`./script2 <line1> 
./script2 <line2> 
./script2 <line3>`

```
./script1 | xargs -I {} ./script2 {}
```

- Remove `{}` from your script to pass each line of output into
  `script2` together  as in - `./script2 <line1> <line2> <line3>`

`./script1 | xargs -L1 ./script2`

Comment: `./script1 | xargs -I {} ./script2 {}` when I do this it runs script2 as if it had no output, but it runs it x times, where x is the number of lines in script 1.

Comment: `./script2 <line1> 
./script2 <line2> 
./script2 <line3>` You're right, this is the behavior I want.

Comment: Ok. Isn't it working for you?, coz it works fine when I tested with my sample script.